# Error when running stoch_simul in dynare on octave

Tags: octave

I have a problem with my dynare/octave. When I run the code our professor uploaded (and which worked for him and my class mates, I get an error message. I found out that the error message comes from the function stoch_simul:
This is the error message.

```
DGGES : parameter number 19 is invalid
error: Fortran procedure terminated by call to XERBLA
```

Since the code should be fine, I thought it might be because of my dynare or octave. I reinstalled both but I still have the same result and tried it with Dynare 4.6.2 and 4.6.3. I have the Octave GNU version 5.2.0

I would appreciate any help!

This is my code:

```
var n y w i a nu r pi rast;
varexo eps_a eps_i;
parameters alpha, rho, theta, varphi, eta_a, phi_pi, phi_y, eta_i, epsilon, mu, piast, beta, kappa, psi;
alpha = 0.3;                // production function
rho = 0.01;                 // time preference rate
varphi = 1;                 // inverse Frisch elasticity
theta = 1;                  // inverse elasticity of intertemporal substitution
eta_a = 0;                  // productivity shock persistence
phi_pi = 1.5;               // interest rate rule parameter
phi_y = 0.125;              // interest rate rule parameter
gamma = 0.667;              // Calvo parameter
eta_i = 0.5;                // monetary policy shock persistence
epsilon = 6;                // elasticity of substitution
mu = epsilon/(epsilon-1);   // mark-up
piast = 0.02;               // inflation target
beta = 1/(1+rho+piast);
kappa = (1-gamma)*(1-gamma*beta)/gamma*(theta*(1-alpha)+varphi+alpha)/(1-alpha+epsilon);
psi = 1+(1-alpha)*(1-theta)/(theta*(1-alpha)+varphi+alpha);

model;
a = eta_a*a(-1) + eps_a;
nu = eta_i*nu(-1) + eps_i;
y = y(+1)-(1/theta)*(i-piast-pi(+1)-rast);
pi = beta*pi(+1) + kappa*y;
r = i - piast - pi(+1);
i = rho + piast + phi_pi*pi + phi_y*y + nu;
rast = rho + theta*psi*(a(+1)-a);
y = a + (1-alpha)*n;
w = theta*y + varphi*n;
end;

initval;
a = 0;
nu = 0;
pi = 0.02;
n = 0.3;
y = 0.6;
w = 1.5;
r = 0.05;
i = 0.03;
rast = 0.03;
end;

steady;

// check;

// Specify temporary shock
shocks;
var eps_a; stderr 0.0075;
var eps_i; stderr 0.003;
end;

stoch_simul(periods=200, drop=100, order=1, irf=12);
```

Comment: I don't recognise `// comments` or `var name` as octave syntax. Also, things like `initval;` and `steady;` are valid syntax, but wouldn't have any effect. I'm not familiar with dynare ... are these files meant to be preprocessed first or something?

Comment: that's dynare code. It's a programm solves macroeconomic systems of equations. You can use it in octave and matlab by executing the command dynare file name.

Comment: The problem has something to do with Fortran/XERBLA but I haven't worked much with octave so I have no clue what to do. I googled the error message but I couldn't find anything

Comment: XERBLA should be one of the Lapack routine for error handling https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/d73/group__aux__blas_ga377ee61015baf8dea7770b3a404b1c07.html

Comment: Thank you for this information. :)